# Create a change password page

Tags: redirect, authentication, passwords, wordpress

I have added a plugin called "force password" which will force members to change their password on their first login.

However, because I redirect the users to a profile page I have done myself, I don't want them to be redirected to the dashboard or to be able edit my profile page.

Instead, I want a screen to popup with a "change my password" box or a change password box to be loaded on a similar page as the login page. After they change their password they will be logged into their profiles.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your question is, but what you need to do is to hook into the wp init action that runs when a request starts.  There you can check if the password has changed, put up the form, check the post values and do your redirects.

Redirects must be done in the init before Wordpress starts writing to the response.